# Errors when hinding sections

Tags: orbeon

We encounter 2 kind of errors on 4.0 Beta3 PE on tomat 7 with exist database

1. with a very simple form. a radiobutton and a section.
   the section visibility is controlled with this statement ($control-3 =
   'two').
   The function works. Clicking on the 2nd radiobutton shows the section.
   Clicking on another hides the section and shows this error

   Undeclared variable in a standalone expression: $fb-can-do-classes in
   oxf:/xbl/orbeon/section/section.xbl line 72
   (org.orbeon.saxon.trans.XPathException)
   Undeclared variable in a standalone expression: $open in
   oxf:/xbl/orbeon/section/section.xbl line 112
   (org.orbeon.saxon.trans.XPathException)
2. the second test form is larger, with mandatory fields and lot of hiding
   of sections and controls. The hiding and showing is done with the same
   statement as with the first form.
   When the user saves the form this error occurs:

   Required item type of first argument of normalize-space() is xs:string;
   supplied value has item type xs:date in
   oxf:/apps/fr/includes/persistence/persistence-model.xml line 306
   (org.orbeon.saxon.trans.XPathException)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news, both are bugs which [just](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/799) [got fixed](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/797).

PS: It's probably better to report bugs to the Orbeon mailing-list or to enter them on github.